# как исправить ошибку при установке mysql?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, lemp

знаю, что есть уже несколько таких вопросов, но решения оттуда мне не помогли.

ставлю LEMP на linux kubuntu 18.04, во время установки mysql-server не запрашивает root-пароль.
пишу sudo mysql_secure_installation, ошибка:

```
some@user-All-Series:~$ sudo mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

при попытке запустить сервис:

```
some@user-All-Series:~$ sudo service mysql start

Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service is masked.
```

как править?

upd:
    some@user-All-Series:~$ sudo systemctl status mysql

```
● mysql.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)

авг 14 10:57:16 user-All-Series mysqld[7100]: 2018-08-14T07:57:16.512821Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 180814 10:57:16
авг 14 10:57:18 user-All-Series mysqld[7100]: 2018-08-14T07:57:18.179893Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1619804
авг 14 10:57:18 user-All-Series mysqld[7100]: 2018-08-14T07:57:18.181836Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
авг 14 10:57:18 user-All-Series mysqld[7100]: 2018-08-14T07:57:18.181853Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
авг 14 10:57:18 user-All-Series mysqld[7100]: 2018-08-14T07:57:18.181859Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
авг 14 10:57:18 user-All-Series mysqld[7100]: 2018-08-14T07:57:18.181864Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
авг 14 10:57:18 user-All-Series mysqld[7100]: 2018-08-14T07:57:18.181867Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
авг 14 10:57:18 user-All-Series mysqld[7100]: 2018-08-14T07:57:18.182034Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
авг 14 10:57:18 user-All-Series mysqld[7100]: 2018-08-14T07:57:18.182268Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
авг 14 10:57:18 user-All-Series systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
```

если сделать `unmask`:

```
some@user-All-Series:~$ sudo systemctl unmask mysql
Removed /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.
some@user-All-Series:~$ sudo systemctl start mysql 
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

содержимое файлов `mysql.service`
    # MySQL systemd service file

```
[Unit]
Description=MySQL Community Server
After=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=mysql
Group=mysql
PIDFile=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
TimeoutSec=600
Restart=on-failure
RuntimeDirectory=mysqld
RuntimeDirectoryMode=755
LimitNOFILE=5000
cat: /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

upd: systemctl status mysql

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-08-14 12:15:57 MSK; 2min 20s ago
  Process: 18752 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

авг 14 12:15:57 user-All-Series systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
авг 14 12:15:57 user-All-Series systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
авг 14 12:15:57 user-All-Series systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
авг 14 12:15:57 user-All-Series systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
авг 14 12:15:59 user-All-Series systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
авг 14 12:15:59 user-All-Series systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
авг 14 12:15:59 user-All-Series systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
авг 14 12:16:01 user-All-Series systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
авг 14 12:16:01 user-All-Series systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
авг 14 12:16:01 user-All-Series systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81632/discussion-on-question-by-dasauser------mysql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не знаю чем это чревато, но после того как я удалил файл FROZEN ИЗ `/etc/mysql/` у меня все заработало.